# Setting up a button onClickListener for EmptyView android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-button

I am working through the Big Nerd Ranch guide for android programming, and I am at the challenge for Chapter 16. The challenge is to make an EmptyView for a ListView, and then make a button on the EmptyView that adds stuff. I got the EmptyView to work but I can't figure out where I should make my button. Here is my code.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v= super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_frame_layout, parent);

return v;
}
```

and here is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="24dp"
android:text="@string/empty_no_crime" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/empty_new_crime"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/empty_new_crime">     
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The book is telling us to use fragments, hence the inflate. I figure the code should be

```
mNewCrime=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.empty_new_crime)
```

but that isn't working. Any ideas?

Edit*: Hmmm, apparently this also really isn't working that well. When I do add stuff, the EmptyView does not go away, it just gets pushed down while items are listed. Any ideas on how to make the EmptyView go away as soon as I add things?

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this challenge at first as well. I over thought it! You have probably solved this issue by now but I thought it would be useful to post an answer for others. The following worked for me:

1. Create a new XML file specifying the "empty" and "list" views as you have done already.
2. Modify your existing onCreateView method to inflate the new modified layout which contains the "empty" and "list" views you have defined in your XML.
3. Create a new button and setup the onClickListener for the button.

Here is the code:

```
@TargetApi(11)
@Override
// We override the onCreateView to set the subtitle by default if we are rocking >3.0 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);   

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        if(mSubtitleVisible){
            getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);
        }// End inner if
    }// End if

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_layout, parent, false);

    mNewCrimeButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add_crime);
    //Define an click event listener for the button and launch the new crime fragment when clicked
    mNewCrimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Crime crime = new Crime();
                    //Get the crimelab from the activity and add the crime
                    CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).addCrime(crime); //getActivity returns the activity this fragment is attached to
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimePagerActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i,0);
                }//End onClick
            });

    return v;
}// End onCreateView
```

This should work with your existing xml layout. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled initially with this, essentially solving it the same way the above poster did. However my problem was a bit different. I was getting bombed out of the application on startup, because my code that set up the onClick listener looked like this:

```
Button mCrimeButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_button);
mCrimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        initiateCrimeRecord();
    }
});
```

It wasn't until I moved the declaration of mCrimeButton up to the class level making it an instance variable of the class that I was able to successfully execute the app:

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private static final String TAG = "CrimeListFragment";
    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;
    private boolean mSubtitleVisible;
    private Button mCrimeButton;
    *
    *
    *

@TargetApi(11)
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_empty_crime_list, parent, false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        if ( mSubtitleVisible) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);
        } else {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle(null);
        }

    }

    // Set the button up on the empty view
    mCrimeButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_button);
    mCrimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            initiateCrimeRecord();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

I then went back and noticed that in all the other examples in the book, the widgets that get manipulated are declared as private instances of the class. Why is this? Android doesn't allow you to just get a local instance to attach the listener?